# Glide for using android recyclerview get Forbidden error (403)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, wampserver, android-glide, http-status-code-403

I am using Glide 4.11.0 to load image from my localhost with url. I wrote same code for an imageview and recyclerview. I have no problem with imageview, but I get forbidden error (403) when use for recyclerview.

I tried to change header, change wampserver settings, add custom OkHttpUrlLoader, add meta-data, add different implementations, add diskCacheStrategy, skipMemoryCache, override.
I know some of them are irrelevant, but I dont know so much thing about that, so I just tried.
None of them solve, or I missed up something.

MyViewHolder

```
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    private ViewDataBinding binding;

    public MyViewHolder(ViewDataBinding binding) {
        super(binding.getRoot());
        this.binding = binding;
    }

    public void bind(final Object obj) {
        binding.setVariable(BR.obj, obj);
        binding.executePendingBindings();

        if(obj instanceof Product){
            ProductItemBinding productBinding = (ProductItemBinding) binding;
            ImageHelper.loadImage(productBinding.imageView, "https://192.168.x.x/"+((Product) obj).getImageUrl());
        }
    }
}
```

ImageHelper

```
public class ImageHelper{
    public static void loadImage(final ImageView imageView, String url){
        GlideApp.with(imageView.getContext())
                .load(url)
                .into(imageView);
    }
}
```

AppGlideModule

```
@GlideModule
public class SimpleAppGlideModule extends AppGlideModule {
    @Override
    public void applyOptions(Context context, GlideBuilder builder) {
        RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions();
        options.placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground);
        builder.setDefaultRequestOptions(options);
    }

    @Override
    public void registerComponents(Context context, Glide glide, Registry registry) {
        OkHttpClient client = HttpHelper.getUnsafeOkHttpClient();
        registry.replace(GlideUrl.class, InputStream.class, new OkHttpUrlLoader.Factory(client));
    }
}
```

OkHttpClient

```
public class HttpHelper {

    public static OkHttpClient getUnsafeOkHttpClient() {
        try {
            // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
            final TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{
                    new X509TrustManager() {
                        @Override
                        public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                            return new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[]{};
                        }
                    }
            };

            // Install the all-trusting trust manager
            final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());

            // Create an ssl socket factory with our all-trusting manager
            final SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();

            OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
            builder.sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory, (X509TrustManager) trustAllCerts[0]);
            builder.hostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
                @Override
                public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                    return true;
                }
            });
            OkHttpClient okHttpClient = builder.build();
            return okHttpClient;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

And implementations:

```
def glideVersion = '4.11.0'

implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:$glideVersion"
annotationProcessor "com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:$glideVersion"
annotationProcessor 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
implementation ("com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp3-integration:$glideVersion")
```

Here is error. Showns for all items.

```
W/Glide: Load failed for https://192.168.x.x/product_images/6.jpg
     with size [535x221]
    class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
    There was 1 cause:
    com.bumptech.glide.load.HttpException(Forbidden)
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
      Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetching data failed, class java.io.InputStream, REMOTE
    There was 1 cause:
    com.bumptech.glide.load.HttpException(Forbidden)
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
        Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetch failed
    There was 1 cause:
    com.bumptech.glide.load.HttpException(Forbidden)
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
          Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.HttpException: Forbidden
I/Glide: Root cause (1 of 1)
    com.bumptech.glide.load.HttpException: Forbidden
        at com.bumptech.glide.integration.okhttp3.OkHttpStreamFetcher.onResponse(OkHttpStreamFetcher.java:71)
        at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:153)
        at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

And also I run app on my device.

**EDIT**

I found problem. When I entered urls in database, I pressed enter without realizing. So added new line and the url was wrong..

Comment: Is there user name and password for the server to access it?

Comment: phpmyadmin has password

Comment: If you called the image url from a browser for the first time, will it ask for username and password?

Comment: No, it doesnt ask

Comment: I had no problem when i try with an imageview. So i was thinking it happend because of recyclerview requests one after another

Comment: @FDK any solution?

Comment: Url was wrong..